# Highlight Cells modified manually and not done via macro.

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I  have been doing a little bit of research if its possible to highlight cells which have been manually amended (by typing in the information) as oppose via marco. What i really came across was track changes which might not apply in this situation

**Scenario**

I have a macro which runs each time certain cells are double clicked. When a cell is double clicked a timestamp is provided, which is perfectly fine.

**Problem**

I am trying to aviod the situation were a user tries to amend the time stamp manually, or any of that information in that relevant cell.  I am trying to aviod using the methdology of locking cells once update.

**Solution to be achieved.**

Is it possible that if a cell has been manually updated by user that its highlighted. However if it has been update through the use of the macro thats ok.

**Code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65

                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username")
                    .Value2 = .Value2 & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

                    End Select
                  End If
    End With
```

Comment: Why not protect these cells?

Comment: Perhaps use a public boolean variable as a flag that the macro would adjust but a manual adjustment wouldn't. The event can just check this flag and act differently.

Comment: @FunThomas i am not using protect cells because its locks the signature lines i have on the page

Comment: @Zerk how would implement that into my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution to this would just to be enforce any changes to your selected cells with the change event. I assume the double click aspect is to make it more user friendly for the input so we won't remove that, rather duplicate it:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
With Target
    If .Column = 4 Then
        Select Case .Row
            Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        End Select
    End If
End With
End Sub
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    With Target
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Else
    For Each cell In Target.Cells
    With cell
        If .Column = 4 Then
            Select Case .Row
                Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
                    .Value2 = "Prepared By" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            End Select
        End If
    End With
    Next cell
End If
End Sub
```